# Anyone have any luck writing a very fast tiff viewer/editor in Java?

Tags: java, tiff, jai

I have explored several leads (sample apps) in the JAI/ImageIO arena, and have so far come up lacking in performance.

It may just be that Java is not the platform for fast viewing/scaling/editing of tiff files.

I am looking to produce performance similar to Irfanview, but so far haven't found what I am looking for.

JAI\ImageIO seems possible - but there seems to be many variations in how one can load/scale/display the images (in so far as performance is concerned).

Anyone have any luck or recommendations for other rocks to turn over (other libraries, or even JNI c extension route) would love to hear them!

Answer (score 3):

I would really recommend the JAI/ImageIO route.

Several years ago I had this same issue of displaying massive tiff files for cropping rotation etc, and after spending some good time with JAI I was able to work with the tiff images without any issues of performance. These were in excess of 90Mb

I'm not able to recall any usefull tips, but you are going in the right direction with JAI. 
I would imagine the performance has increased over the years too :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - hearing 'its possible' is the answer I like!  I would vote this up but don't have the Rep.